# How, with CoreData to: Select distinct measuretype from BM_Measures where measureAccount=x

Tags: core-data, distinct

I have a bunch of account objects which have a to-many relationship to "measures"...
account.measures<--->measure.measureaccount

I am trying to return, for any particular account, the distinct measure types - designated as Strings in the core data model:

[image]

But I get all the individual measure types:

```
- (NSArray *)getDistinctMeasuresForAccount: (BM_Account *)account
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *myContext=[self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BM_Measure" inManagedObjectContext:myContext];
    [findObjects setEntity:entity];

    NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
    [findObjects setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"measuretype"]]];

    [findObjects setReturnsDistinctResults:TRUE];
    findObjects.fetchBatchSize=1;
    findObjects.fetchLimit=0;
    NSPredicate *myObjectPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"measureAccount = %@",account];
    findObjects.predicate=myObjectPredicate;
    findObjects.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    NSSortDescriptor *sortReturnedObjects=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"measuretype" ascending:FALSE];
    findObjects.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortReturnedObjects, nil];
    NSError *findError;
    NSArray *databaseObjects=[myContext executeFetchRequest:findObjects error:&findError];
    if(databaseObjects==nil){
        NSLog(@"BM.DB.getDistinctMeasuresForAccount: Unable to execute query to get Objects");
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"About to return %ld %@",[databaseObjects count],databaseObjects);
        return(databaseObjects);
    }
    NSLog(@"BM.DB.getDistinctMeasuresForAccount: Returning zero because of open query");
    return 0;


}
```

Output:

```
About to return 347 (
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
        {
        measuretype = Weight;
    },
...
```

Comment: Your fetch request looks good to me, but perhaps we are both overlooking something obvious. Can you add "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" to the program launch arguments (in the Scheme editor)? Then you will see the SQL request for the fetch request in the console.

Comment: Maybe because the NSStrings are not == but [isEqual]?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you show the SQL command for the fetch request, as suggested above?

Comment: Nope - doesn't show anything

Comment: Is this a "normal" Core Database, using a SQLite file as store, or something "special" (StackMob, ...) ?

Comment: Created a "vanilla" core data app on OSX with Xcode Version 5.0.1 (5A2034a)

Comment: Then I have no idea. I could also not reproduce the behavior.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40404/discussion-between-jeremylaurenson-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the default constructor in the latest version of Xcode creates an xml database - and so distinct is not supported.